# using ajax update panel for update progress

Tags: c#, ajax

can any one guide me in showing the update progress while retreiving large records from a database.while clicking the search in button an aspx page it should close that page and show the update progress in  an other aspx page .

Comment: @subash from tirunelveli

Comment: iam also frm tiruchendur.where do du work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hai subash Try this put this in your master page next to `<Body>`

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server"
                 DynamicLayout="false" DisplayAfter="0">
<ProgressTemplate>


<div class="loading" style="padding-left:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    Loading...&nbsp
</div>
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

.CSS:

```
.loading {
   background-color:#404040;
height:23px;position:fixed;font-weight:bold;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:3px;-webkit-

border-bottom-left-radius:3px;   -moz-border-radius-bottomright:3px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
color:#fff;   top:0px;   left:45%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you you want to redirect to another page, you probably don't need Ajax. BTW you can simply put an UpdateProgress where ever an UpdatePanel exists. UpdateProgress' content will be showed automatically when a partial Postback occurs.